# How to correctly use C++ strongly typed enumerations?

Tags: c++, enums, c++11

I want to use the C++11 scoped enums with the default int implementation:

```
enum class Color
{
    gray          = 1,  
    red           = 2
};
```

This compiles with gcc, but:

```
Color color = Color::red;  // 'Color' is not a class or a namespace
Color color = red;         // 'red' was not declared in this scope
```

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

This should be compilable, but it isn't, at least for me. I am using gcc version 4.6.1 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.1-9ubuntu3). When I try:

```
 make -std=c++0x -w in /home/martin/Projects/StrongTypedEnums-build-desktop
```

I get

```
:-1: error: invalid option -- '='.
```

I am doing everything via IDE and have no idea about passing compiler arguments whatsoever.

```
enum class Color
{
    gray          = 1,
    red           = 2
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Color color = Color::red; // 'Color' is not a class or a namespace
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can't say you want to use scoped enums and then try to ignore scope.

Comment: but Color color = Color::red; does not compile also. How can I fix it?

Comment: `Color color = red;` is an error, but `Color color = Color::red; ` should be okay.

Comment: What version of GCC are you using? Are you compiling with the C++11 switch set?

Comment: @Nicol yes, I get a warning: scoped enums only available with -std=c++0x or -std=gnu++0x [enabled by default]

Comment: @MartinDrozdik: If you're getting that warning, then you're *not* compiling with the C++11 switch set.

Comment: @NicolBolas I found out I am using gcc version 4.6.1 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.1-9ubuntu3). Also "To enable C++0x support, add the command-line parameter -std=c++0x to your g++ command line" but when I try: make -std=c++0x -w in /home/martin/Projects/StrongTypedEnums-build-desktop I get :-1: error: invalid option -- '='. Please, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why don't you post a [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example of your code?](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: @MartinDrozdik you need to add the -std=c++0x parameter to the g++ command line, not make.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandez Thank you! That was the problem all along :D I use only an automatically created makefile, but I found out that I can pass the parameter by adding QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++0x to the Qt .pro file. Then the program compiles and has the desired behaviour.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Strongly-typed enums *require* scoping. You *must* prefix them with `EnumName::`, just as though they were `static` members of a class. Regular enums in C++11 can optionally be prefixed, but strongly-typed ones require it.

C++11 essentially three new features added to enums:

- Explicit typing (`enum class EnumName : int`)
- lexical scoping (`EnumName::` syntax)
- strong typing.

You can get the first two with regular enums (backwards compatibility makes both of them optional for non-`class` enums). But the only way to get strong typing is with `enum class`, which requires both of the others (if you don't specify an explicit type for `enum class` declarations, I believe it uses `int`).

The enforced scoping means that you generally don't need to ALL_CAPS enumerator names for `enum class`es, since you have to explicitly scope them anyway.

Comment: "you generally don't need to ALL_CAPS enumerator names for enum classes, since you have to explicitly scope them anyway" - IMHO you never should have done that anyway - best practice being to use all-caps for preprocessor macros, except for single-letter or single-letter + single-digit identifiers which are often used for template parameters....

Comment: The big reason for scoping is to allow multiple enums to have the same enumerator name and not be ambiguous.  Several enums could all have a NONE for example, or an END or LAST for another example.  It prevents you from having to make prefixes to enumerators.

Comment: @ emsr how is typing EnumName:: every time different from typing a prefix?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem using Code::Blocks 10.05 using GCC.

What I had to do was go to Project > Build Options, select my project name on the left pane (not "Debug" or "Release").  Then, under the selected compiler "GNU GCC Compiler", under "Compiler Settings", "Compiler Flags", I checked "Have g++ follow the coming C++0x ISO C++ language standard [-std=c++0x]."